# Flutter how to make previous page method on onboarding screen and how to make onboardingscreen only 1 time

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i'm new to flutter and now i'm working a project for my university project.

so i i already make an OnboardingScreen, but it cannot go to the previous page, i can make it go the next page with pagecontroller but i cannot make it go to previous page. i actually don't really know how to add the Text('Prev') because i already use align bottom right for the next.

if it isn't clear to you, may this photo helps

[i want to make prev in bottom left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNvQ3.png)

i also want to make the onboardingScreen only 1 time, i already search about the sharedpreference but i don't really know how to use it (i do accept any other method, as long my OnboardingScreen only 1 time)

here are the full code for my OnboardingScreen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:movie_app_3/screens/home_screen.dart';


class Onboarding extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnboardingScreen createState() => _OnboardingScreen();
}

class _OnboardingScreen extends State<Onboarding> {
  final int _numPages = 3;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int _currentPage = 0;

  List<Widget> _buildPageIndicator() {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < _numPages; i++) {
      list.add(i == _currentPage ? _indicator(true) : _indicator(false));
    }
    return list;
  }

  Widget _indicator(bool isActive) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      height: 8.0,
      width: isActive ? 24.0 : 16.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isActive ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF7B51D3),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
              colors: [
                Colors.black,
                Color(0xff112339),
                Color(0xff112339),
                Colors.black,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Skip',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 600.0,
                  child: PageView(
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _pageController,
                    onPageChanged: (int page) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentPage = page;
                      });
                    },
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:70.0,left: 40.0,right: 40.0,),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/Logo.png',
                                ),
                                height: 120.0,
                                width: 120.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                            Text(
                              'Welcome',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 21.0,
                                height: 1.5,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Welcome to Moviez, the place where you will spend your time magically',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                height: 1.2,
                                fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:70.0,left: 40.0,right: 40.0,),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/Logo.png',
                                ),
                                height: 120.0,
                                width: 120.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                            Text(
                              'Purpose',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 21.0,
                                height: 1.5,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'This App is for educational purposes only',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                height: 1.2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:70.0,left: 40.0,right: 40.0,),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/Logo.png',
                                ),
                                height: 120.0,
                                width: 120.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                            Text(
                              'Creator',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 21.0,
                                height: 1.5
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Adela, Caroline, Cordellya, David, Valentino',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                height: 1.2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: _buildPageIndicator(),
                ),
                _currentPage != _numPages - 1
                    ? Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _pageController.nextPage(
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.ease,
                              );
                            },
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Next',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 22.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 30.0,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Text(''),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: _currentPage == _numPages - 1
          ? Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: GestureDetector(
               onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
                );
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Get started',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF5B16D0),
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Text(''),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the code for my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:movie_app_3/widget/onboard.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
         
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Onboarding(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want one-time onboarding you can set a key called for example finishedOnBoarding in sharedpreferences when the user finishes the onboarding then you can check whether this key exist or not to determine if the user already finished onboarding so if the key exist let him go to the main page if not start onboarding.

Comment: It's clear to me that you want to show the onboarding screen only once for a new user, but it's unclear to me about "prev" text.Can you please clear about it?

Comment: i have edit the question, i add a photo to it can you look at it, sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Question 1 : For `Prev` button, you can use `Row` and `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`

```
Expanded(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
             ...
            Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
             ...
```

Question 2: For `Onboarding` show only once, you can use `initialRoute`

```
bool seen;
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  seen = prefs.getBool("seen") ?? false;
  print(seen.toString());
  await prefs.setBool("seen", true);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     ...
      initialRoute: seen == false ? "/onboarding" : "/home",
      routes: {
        '/home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        "/onboarding": (context) => Onboarding(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Onboarding extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnboardingScreen createState() => _OnboardingScreen();
}

class _OnboardingScreen extends State<Onboarding> {
  final int _numPages = 3;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int _currentPage = 0;

  List<Widget> _buildPageIndicator() {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < _numPages; i++) {
      list.add(i == _currentPage ? _indicator(true) : _indicator(false));
    }
    return list;
  }

  Widget _indicator(bool isActive) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      height: 8.0,
      width: isActive ? 24.0 : 16.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isActive ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF7B51D3),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
              colors: [
                Colors.black,
                Color(0xff112339),
                Color(0xff112339),
                Colors.black,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Skip',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 500.0,
                  child: PageView(
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _pageController,
                    onPageChanged: (int page) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentPage = page;
                      });
                    },
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 70.0,
                          left: 40.0,
                          right: 40.0,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                  'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                                ),
                                height: 120.0,
                                width: 120.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                            Text(
                              'Welcome',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 21.0,
                                height: 1.5,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Welcome to Moviez, the place where you will spend your time magically',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                height: 1.2,
                                fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 70.0,
                          left: 40.0,
                          right: 40.0,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                  'https://picsum.photos/250?image=10',
                                ),
                                height: 120.0,
                                width: 120.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                            Text(
                              'Purpose',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 21.0,
                                height: 1.5,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'This App is for educational purposes only',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                height: 1.2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 70.0,
                          left: 40.0,
                          right: 40.0,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                  'https://picsum.photos/250?image=11',
                                ),
                                height: 120.0,
                                width: 120.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                            Text(
                              'Creator',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 21.0,
                                  height: 1.5),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Adela, Caroline, Cordellya, David, Valentino',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                height: 1.2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: _buildPageIndicator(),
                ),
                _currentPage != _numPages - 1
                    ? Expanded(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Align(
                              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                              child: TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _pageController.previousPage(
                                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                    curve: Curves.ease,
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_back,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      size: 30.0,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                    Text(
                                      'Prev',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 22.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                              child: TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _pageController.nextPage(
                                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                    curve: Curves.ease,
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      'Next',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 22.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      size: 30.0,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    : Text(''),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: _currentPage == _numPages - 1
          ? Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
                  );
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Get started',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF5B16D0),
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Text(''),
    );
  }
}

bool seen;
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  seen = prefs.getBool("seen") ?? false;
  print(seen.toString());
  await prefs.setBool("seen", true);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: seen == false ? "/onboarding" : "/home",
      routes: {
        '/home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        "/onboarding": (context) => Onboarding(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```